# Lack of Magento order creation after paypal payment

Tags: orders

We had a customer contact us (and forwarded their paypal order confirmation) of an order placed with us (and paid successfully through PayPal, which showed all order items and details) but on Magento there is no trace of this order, no order was created and no invoice raised.

How could this happen?  Is there anything we can do to stop it happening?

Comment: Paypal Express or regular Paypal? Also what version of Magento?

Comment: Magento 1.8.1.0, and using PayPal express.  There is an invoice number (100019216) mentioned on the PayPal email which the customer has received, but this invoice does not exist.  In fact out highest invoice number is about 100018000 ish

Comment: Any trace of that order or exceptions while creating it in system.log, exception.log or paypal_express_ipn.log?

Comment: Our logs have been turned off unfortunately!